# How do you get the PID of a kotlin coroutine Job?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kill-process

How do i get the PID of a kotlin coroutine Job? Since coroutines don't provide methods to instantly kill the job, I was thinking of using android.os.Process.killProcess() instead to kill the process that executes *external code*. But it requires the PID of the thread.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Coroutines run on threads from thread pools, and switch threads potentially every time a suspend function is encountered, so they don't run on a single thread anyway. If you do kill one of these reusable threads, it will break the dispatcher system, which will break any current or future running coroutines. You should instead write your coroutine so it cooperates with cancellation.

Comment: @Tenfour04 The problem is that the program is java executor so if the code contains infinite while loops, the code would never complete and hence would never stop, causing high memory usage

Comment: @PranavPurwar your infinite loop needs to check if its task has been cancelled, and stop looping (and do any finalisation required). That goes for coroutines, threads, whatever - you shouldn't *need* to kill them. Have a read of this: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/cancellation-and-timeouts.html#cancellation-is-cooperative

Answer (score 0):

First, as said in comments coroutines don't run on their own thread.  Second-  you NEVER kill a thread from an outside thread.  Doing so is *NOT* safe.  You don't know what that thread is doing, what resources it may hold, and what it may be doing at that exact time.  Instead, you cancel them by setting a flag somewhere which it periodically checks to see if its canceled.  Not following this rule means you could leave the app in a bad state unable to do anything, or cause memory corruption as objects are in half changed states, or leave the entire app deadlocked as semaphores/mutexes are not properly released.  There's a reason why the Thread.stop() function in Java has been deprecated for nearly 20 years.